# :JSON unable to read result of Web Service

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

I have web service method as follow,

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = FetchSitePerformanceAuto/{fromDate}/{country}")]
public List<DailyBingRTT_Performance_Last7Days_Result> FetchSitePerformanceAuto(string fromDate, string country)
{

   SitePerformance objSiteP = new SitePerformance();
   List<DailyBingRTT_Performance_Last7Days_Result> l = new     List<DailyBingRTT_Performance_Last7Days_Result>();
   l = objSiteP.getPerformanceByDateAndCountry(fromDate, country);
   WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
   return l;
}
```

When I call this method directly in browser it returns,

```
{"FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult":[{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 03, 2013","Performance":106917},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 04, 2013","Performance":119542},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 05, 2013","Performance":106917},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 06, 2013","Performance":119542},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 07, 2013","Performance":106917},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 08, 2013","Performance":119542},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 09, 2013","Performance":106917}]}
```

But when I try to call this service method using following code,

```
var newUrl = 'http://someurl:55250/BeingEdgeService.svc/FetchSitePerformanceAuto/11-09-2013/India?'

$.getJSON(newUrl, function (result) {
   alert('Length  ' + result.length);
});
```

it returns undefined.

In addition, I have one more method in service as

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = FetchSitePerformanceAuto/{fromDate}/{country}")]
    public Stream FetchSitePerformanceStream(string fromDate, string country)
            {
                SitePerformance objSiteP = new SitePerformance();
                List<DailyBingRTT_Performance_Last7Days_Result> l = new List<DailyBingRTT_Performance_Last7Days_Result>();
                l = objSiteP.getPerformanceByDateAndCountry(fromDate, country);

                var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(l));
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(json);
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                return memoryStream;

            }
```

When this method is called from using `$.getJSON` it returns correct result.
I think issues is on service side may be.

I executed my Code using Fiddler, result is

```
{"FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult":[{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 01, 2013","Performance":106917},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 02, 2013","Performance":119542}]}
```

Is it a correct JSON? cause not able to parse it.

Comment: Do you use fiddler? What's the response returned there?

Comment: how to use it? can u guide me pls?

Comment: If you don't have it you can download it from [Here](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler). There's instructions on how to use it there. So you'll be able to track every request and response from the browser.

Comment: I have installed it , Bytes Received:  1,024  (headers:603; body:421)
 in call of web service.and application/json: 421

Comment: As I can see JSON response is correct, then what is issue?

Comment: Try `result.FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult.length`

Comment: @Dumisani, I have found my answer already & now I am clear with how I can deal with my code, still Thanks you so much 4 ur time mate.

Comment: Great. Post your solution as an answer to help someone else in future. Then mark it as correct tomorrow.

Comment: @Dumisani, Nice thought , will do that.

Answer (score 0):

what do you get when you execute this:

```
$.getJSON(newUrl, function (result) {
   alert('Length  ' + result);
});
```

Instead of result.length, just use result variable to view the response. 
Since the response is encapsulated inside JSON object, you may get the data returned by server by accessing "result.data".

Hope this helps.

Comment: result.data is undefined

Comment: Please use browser's log to see the response returned by the server. If your service returns data when directly called via browser, then there is no reason it will not return data when calling from jquery.

Comment: What do you get with alert('Length  ' + result);

Comment: Yes I agree friend, but I am facing that issue only, I have updated my ans pls take a look.

Comment: I guess you must have mistyped in question, but the url of newUrl variable should be inside single quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54271/discussion-between-ak47-and-amit-mittal).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON(newUrl, function (result) {
   alert('Length  ' + result.length);
});
```

is not wrong instead it is incomplete.

As my JSON will return object I should have done as,

```
alert('Length  ' + result.FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult.length);
```

I came across this through comments below my questions.